# Do any images exist of Moff Gideon's combat helmet?

Tags: star-wars, object-identification, the-mandalorian

It is notable that Moff Gideon's dark-colored battle armor and cape resemble the style of Darth Vader/Kylo Ren. As an Imperial officer equipped for hand-to-hand combat, I can't imagine Moff Gideon dueling -an opponent- without a helmet. Are there any images, in or out of Canon/Legend, showing Moff Gideon's combat helmet?

[image: Still from The Mandalorian-S01E07-Chapter 7-The Reckoning]

Comment: "As an Imperial officer equipped for hand-to-hand combat, I can't imagine Moff Gideon dueling -an opponent- without a helmet" — why? Have we seen any Imperial officers duel *with* a helmet, except for Darth Vader?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Imperial office battle armor consisted of (among other parts) a blast helmet. Grand Moff Tarkin donned one when confronting Kanan Jarrus. Grand Admiral Thrawn, Governor Arihnda Pryce, General Maximilian Veers, Officer Viggen, Commander Ryden also wore helmets. 
https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Imperial_officer_battle_armor

Comment: Cowards and brigands all! That sort of lily-livered behaviour is whah led to the Empire's downfall in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

The only helmet that Moff Gideon has been canonically seen to wear is part of his [beskar Dark Trooper armor](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Fourth-generation_design_Dark_Trooper) in *The Mandalorian* Season Three:

[image: Moff Gideon wearing black Mandalorian-style armor]

The armor as a whole appears inspired by the armor of [Mandalorian super commandos](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mandalorian_super_commando), as well as the sleeves and legs of [Darth Vader's armor](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Vader%27s_armor). If he ever had another helmet, it hasn't been shown, even when piloting a TIE fighter in Season One.

Comment: Not even piloting a TIE?  I thought that TIEs didn't have full environment support, so the helmet was necessary for breathing?  But, well, Disney.

Comment: @DavidW He was flying in the atmosphere and had no reason to think he would leave it